# opencv The function is not implemented

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I use anaconda3 and write code in ipython notebook. This is my code:

```
import cv2
if __name__ == '__main__':
    img1 = cv2.imread("./frame1.jpg")
    cv2.imshow('show', img1)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /opt/conda/conda-bld/opencv-suite_1527005194613/work/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:636: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage
```

I already have had `libgtk2.0-dev` and `pkg-config`, I have also had `opencv` out from anaconda. 
Later I've installed `opencv` with conda install. But it isn't helping.

Comment: Can you explain your situation a bit more into details?

Comment: I edit my question. You could see, please

Comment: try using matplotlib.pyplot.imshow() instead of cv2.imshow().

Answer (score 0):

Maybe anaconda package does not have highgui library. Try installing system `opencv` library.

```
apt install opencv
```

Comment: Where should I write this? In terminal?

Comment: You are realy need realtyme in browser?

Answer (score 0):

The versions of `opencv` provided by `pip` do not produce this error. From your conda environment, use `pip` to install opencv:

```
pip install opencv-python
```